# Could one say that one dataset is distributed more normally than another?

Tags: r, linear-model, normality-assumption, qq-plot

I am trying to fit a simple linear model: `experiment ~ calculated_1`.  From the basic model, I get `residuals_1`. And I know that another calculated data set can theoretically improve prediction of the experimental data. So I create the other model: `experiment ~ I(calculated_1 + calculated_2)`. From this I get `residuals_2`.

```
residuals_1 <- c(-0.6512352, -0.7809935, 0.4313386, -0.1061949, -0.5986882, -0.8560606, 
                  0.4278563, 0.6283887, -1.0142389, -0.8876992, 0.1680664, 0.2761103, 
                  0.6310700, 0.2358954, -0.1694672, -0.1466784, 0.2525157, 1.6015804, 
                 -0.1060606, 1.2452776, -0.8153085, 0.2490334, -0.0145075)

residuals_2 <- c(-0.684552455, -1.020307239, 0.868944787, 0.191034959, -0.318848920, 
                 -0.961003963, -0.687738963, 1.460222114, -1.092411033, -0.480501852, 
                 -0.043288749, -0.231946550, 0.504105347, 0.753821856, -0.036888490, 
                  0.226492631, 0.197110863, 0.350608105, -0.156642627, 2.078234441, 
                 -1.508965041 ,0.004402459, 0.588118321)
qqnorm(residuals_1)
```

[image: qqnorm_res1]

```
qqnorm(residuals_2)
```

[image: qqnorm_res2]

As one can notice the variance of `residuals_2` is slightly greater then the variance of `residual_1`. But is it correct to say that adding `calculated_2` term make the residuals to be more likely normally distributed? And provide a better description of the experimental data?

Comment: Why do you think more normal residuals improve the predictive strength of a model?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible for one set of data to more closely approximate a given theoretical distribution than another.  One way to think about how close one distribution is to another is to use the [Kullback-Leibler divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence).  This is a measure of how much [information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory) is lost by using one distribution instead of the other.  More specifically, we can determine the information loss associated with using the densities from a true normal fitted to your data instead of a more flexible [kernel density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) fitted to your data.

```
library(flexmix)
sim = function(x, ref){     # find similar values
  lr   = length(ref)
  indx = vector(length=lr)
  for(i in 1:lr){
    indx[i] = which(abs(x-ref[i])==min(abs(x-ref[i])))
  }
  return(indx)
}
get.kl = function(res){     # get densities & K-L divergence
  d.k = density(res)
  d.k = d.k$y[sim(d.k$x, res)]
  d.n = dnorm(res, mean=mean(res), sd=sd(res))
  return(KLdiv(cbind(d.k, d.n))[1,2])
}

get.kl(residuals_1)  # [1] 0.01309022
get.kl(residuals_2)  # [1] 0.005502055
```

More than twice as much information would be lost when approximating `residuals_1` by a normal than approximating `residuals_2`.

---

It is also possible for a misspecified model to yield non-normal residuals:

```
set.seed(3)
x = runif(30, min=0, max=10)
g = rep(0:1, each=15)
y = 17 - 0.3*x + 2*g + rnorm(30)

m1 = lm(y~x)
m2 = lm(y~x+g)
get.kl(resid(m1))  # [1] 0.04971849
get.kl(resid(m2))  # [1] 0.008378342
```

[image]

---

Having said those things, using how closely your residuals approximate a normal distribution to select between models with different covariates would be rather odd.  It is much more typical for people to select between models using a hypothesis test (if the models are nested), the AIC (if they are not nested), out of sample predictive error via cross-validation (if prediction is the ultimate goal of the model), etc.  People do (and should) evaluate the residuals of their models, but they might use that to determine if a transformation is necessary, or if they should bootstrap instead of rely on the standard errors, for example.

Comment: Great answer. And nice bit at the end. Could you expand a bit more on this  point, as I am not sure what it is saying. "or if they should bootstrap instead of rely on the standard errors". Bootstrap to do what?

Comment: Thank you very much for so complete and helpful answer! Predictive perfomance evaluation is not the main goal o this study but I shall do it. THanks for the hint. Am I right that according to K-L divergence information lost in case of residuals_2 is lower in comparison with residuals_1?

Comment: @MHH, the standard errors that come with your output assume the sampling distribution is distributed as a normal or t. If the sampling distribution isn't, then your inferences would be invalid. You can bootstrap to get an empirical estimate of the sampling distribution, which you can use for inference instead.

Comment: @dkarlov, yes, according to K-L divergence information lost in case of residuals_2 is lower in comparison with residuals_1.